# The attribute "maxRowSelection" was not found on the COMPONENT

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have used lightning:datatable to show table data. This component's properties like maxRowSelection, showRowNumberColumn are not working. I am getting error

> The attribute "maxRowSelection" was not found on the COMPONENT
>   markup://lightning:datatable

LC source

```
<lightning:datatable data="{! v.allergyList }" columns="{! v.allergyListColumns }" keyField="id" onrowselection="{! c.getSelectedName }" maxRowSelection="1" />
```

Is any one faced same issue? Please suggest on this issue.

Comment: Please Share your code

Comment: In the future, please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure, that API version of the compoennt is `42.0`  but not lower, as only with Spring '18 release those attributes are available

here is [release notes](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_lc_components.htm?edition=&impact=) about adding `maxRowSelection` attribute to `lightning:datatable` component

Comment: I am wondering why Salesforce didn't introduce it earlier. This attribute could be so helpful! Well, better late than never...